# Is a species that mates by "tribadism" possible?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, reproduction, sex

In real life, there are planarians that are hermaphroditic, which means that they produce both eggs and sperm, however,  they have penises and scrotum without clitorises and vaginas. They sexually reproduce by penis fencing (which is comparable to the gay sexual practice of frotting in mammals).

[image]

In my world, there is a hermaphroditic species that is the polar opposite of planarians: they have clitorises and vaginas without penises and scrotum.

So, I wonder if a hermaphroditic species, or even an all-female species, that reproduce by the homologue of the lesbian sexual practice of tribadism could exist.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Not all reptiles or birds have penises, or external testes. Such creatures transfer sperm by a "[cloacal kiss](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cloacal_kiss)".

So yes, not only is it possible, it actually exists in real life.